# How can I find a common pattern between sentences?

Tags: nlp

Let's say I have three sentences

> The war caused not only destruction and death but also generations of
> hatred between the two communities.
>
> This investigation is not only one that is continuing and worldwide
> but also one that we expect to continue for quite some time.
>
> The car not only is economical but also feels good to drive.

Is it possible to find the **not only... but also** pattern automatically using NLP, considering I'm not looking for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer, I think, is boring -- sure, it can be the case that recurrent neural network\LSTM will capture this particular pattern, if it helps it to better solve task at hand.

Comment: Why don't you simply look for tokens which occure in all sentences?

Comment: @cronoik This could be a simple solution to the example I gave, but I wanted to expand it so that it would find all types of coordinate conjunctions.

Comment: Yes I think that should be doable with a transformer. This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.11544.pdf) used Bert for a cc task. As far as I know there is no ready to use solution. You have to build it by yourself. You can of course benefit from transformers library provided by [huggingface](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers).